# adb start-server and listen on all interfaces

Tags: adb, windows

ADB in Android 4.3 SDK implemented `-a` option. What I want is:

```
adb -a start-server
```

so the background process is bound to all interfaces, but it does not work. I need to start it like this on Windows. I have managed to start the server in foreground mode with the following command:

```
adb -P 5037 -a fork-server server
```

(copied it from Linux)

Is there any proper way of achieving the same?

Answer (score 4):

This is a bug in the current implementation. Although `adb` has the `-a` flag, it doesn't forward it to the daemon when it launches it, so the daemon still only listens on `localhost`. Until this is fixed, launching the daemon in the foreground seems to be the only solution.

Another improvement would be to keep the command server on localhost, but to allow `adb forward` to bind to all ports. I guess I should open a bug for that.

Comment: Just to add to the answer, this is the command to start it in foreground: `adb nodaemon server`

Comment: This is really a solution. Checked and launching server in foreground with `adb -a nodaemon server` really makes it listen on all ports (while `-H` and `-P` arguments seem to be respected by `adb` in the client mode only). As of version 1.0.36, adb client still doesn't forward the `-a` option to the daemon. Also, running in foreground is a good thing in itself if you want to launch it using init system like systemd.

Comment: ADB 1.0.41 still have this issue, `adb -a start-server` doesn't makes adb server listen on all interfaces, it listens localhost only.

Answer (score 2):

The only way of doing this is recompiling adb as explained here:
http://rxwen.blogspot.com/2009/11/adb-for-remote-connections.html
You can also use the precompiled binaries from that site..